# Ruby equivalent of htmlspecialchars_decode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-parsing

Is there an equivalent of [htmlspecialchars_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php) (PHP) in Ruby (for a Ruby-on-Rails application)

Or something close or similar?

Comment: Can you provide more context on your use-case for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
require("cgi")
CGI.unescapeHTML("&lt;characters")
```